# Using derived Method in Base-Class withing library development

Tags: c++, gcc, polymorphism

I'm writing a small Game-Engine (which is used as a library) while re-reading myself into c++. I've coded in Java for several years, but it seems like c++ handles polymorphism a little bit different and I am encountering the following problem:

I have a class **GameObject**, which represents the basic functionalities of any type of object within the game. So this basically is used as an abstract class.
I have several Objects, which override GameObject including a class **Map**. These objects are finally used within the game.

All this is compiled into a library and used by the game.

Here is the basic code I use:
gameobject.h:

```
class GameObject {
    public:
        void loadFromJson(nlohmann::json& json);
        void load();
    // [...] not relevant
}
```

gameobject.cpp:

```
void GameObject::loadFromJson(nlohmann::json& json) {
    // [...] not relevant
    std::cout << "base-class function" << std::endl;
}

void GameObject::load() {
    // [...] not relevant
    this->loadFromJson(json);
}
```

map.h:

```
class Map : public GameObject {
    public:
        void loadFromJson(nlohmann::json& json);
        // [...] not relevant
}
```

map.cpp:

```
void Map::loadFromJson(nlohmann::json& json) {
    // [...] not relevant
    GameObject::loadFromJson(json);
    std::cout << "derived class function" << std::endl;
}
```

main within game:

```
int main() {
    Map* map = new Map(...);
    map->load();
}
```

I'm not sure which arguments within the makefile are relevant or not, therefore I simply paste all I use, including libraries, which should be irrelevant:
makefile, gameengine (called gct):

```
COMPARGS=-Wall -I$(INCLUDEPATH) -I$(LIBPATH) -I$(LIBPATHGLADINCLUDE) -std=c++17 -fsanitize=address -fPIC $(SDL_FLAGS) $(PKG_FLAGS) -lplibfnt -lSOIL -lstdc++fs -g

$(OUTPUTPATH)libgct.so: [...] gameobject [...] map
$(CC) -shared [...] gameobject [...] map -o $(OUTPUTPATH)libgct.so

gameobject: $(SRCPATH)gameobject.cpp $(INCLUDEPATHGCT)gameobject.h
$(CC) $(SRCPATH)gameobject.cpp -c -o gameobject $(COMPARGS)

map: $(SRCPATHMAP)map.cpp $(INCLUDEPATHGCTMAP)map.h
$(CC) $(SRCPATHMAP)map.cpp -c -o map $(COMPARGS)
```

makefile, game:

```
COMPARGS=-Wall -std=c++17 -fsanitize=address -I$(LIBINCLUDE) -lgct -lplibfnt -lplibul $(SDL_FLAGS) $(PKG_FLAGS) -lSOIL -lstdc++fs -g

testgame: $(SRCPATH)main.cpp [...]
$(CC) $(SRCPATH)main.cpp [...] $(COMPARGS) -o testgame
```

Now my expected behavior would be the output:
"base-class function"
"derived class function"

But what I get is:
"base-class function"

I already had problems with using polymorphism within the library in the way, that loadFromJson() was virtual in base class. And using it with an array of GameObjects (at that time it was with other classes and other methods, but the priciple behind it should become clear). This caused strange errors, which google explained with that such polymorphism is slow, and not supposed to be used within libraries. I know, there shouldn't be much of a difference with this way of polymorphism, but I don't get any errors. Just not the expected behavior and I have the feeling this should work.

However that was a different problem with other classes and other methods which I was able to workaround. But this would be quite anoying, if I wasn't able to use it, since I would have to rewrite load() within the derived classes over and over again.
I found other posts with a (relativly) similar Problem regarding polymorphism, but there the answers always represented my expected behavior.
So my question is: What are the possibilities why this is not working as I want to, or more precise: could this be a result of using the code as a shared library? Maybe there is a error within the code I can't find...I hope and think, that the code I gave you should be enough. I doupt, that it's anything else. If, however, the problem must be somewhere else, I would be glad about some potential mistakes, that could cause this.

Comment: *"This caused strange errors"* -I'll bet a dollar those strange errors were due to [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) and your google search sent you down the wrong rabbit hole. Regardless, the kind of behavior you want is lock stock and both-barrels polymorphism. `loadFromJson` should be at least virtual, if not pure-virtual, in `GameObject`. and should be `override` attributed in any derivations.

Comment: Without making method `virtual` you are simply not getting any polymorphism so `this->loadFromJson(json);` is expected to invoke `GameObject::loadFromJson`.

Comment: Example using smart pointers, a vector container, and proper polymorphism [cam be seen here](https://ideone.com/CjbUQN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void GameObject::load() {
    // [...] not relevant
    this->loadFromJson(json);
}
```

This will always invoke `GameObject::loadFromJson`, even when you declared a subclass `Map` with a `loadFromJson` method.

In Java you will expect an instance of `Map` to result in `Map`'s `loadFromJson`() getting invoked from `load()`. However, C++ is not Java, and ordinary class methods do not get overridden from subclasses by default.

To make them overridable you must use the `virtual` keyword in the base class:

```
class GameObject {
    public:
        virtual void loadFromJson(nlohmann::json& json);
        void load();
    // [...] not relevant
};
```

This will make this method work similarly to how the equivalent code in Java would work, and `Map`'s method will now get invoked, in this case.

Furthermore, this is not required but you should also explicitly declare the subclass method as `virtual` with the `override` keyword, when using the current C++ standard:

```
class Map : public GameObject {
    public:
        virtual void loadFromJson(nlohmann::json& json) override;
        // [...] not relevant
};
```

This is not required to implement a virtual method dispatch, but this will help your C++ compiler yell at you if you make a mistake or a typo, in the future. It's quite common to add a parameter, or change something about the method in the base class, but forget to do it in the subclass. Marking a subclass method as a virtually overridden method will result in a compilation error, were that to happen, alerting you to the problem.

For more information about virtual methods and how to correctly override them (which in C++ you can control on a method-by-method basis), see the relevant chapters in your C++ book.

Comment: Ah ok! Can you quickly explain what the virtual keyword means? I don't know why, but I always thought it's used for empty methods...Tbh relativly stupid by me...because then there would be 4 or something like that different variations how to declare empty methods in c++

Comment: You must be referring to "pure virtual methods", which would be a declaration that looks like "`virtual void loadFromJson(nlohmann::json& json)=0;`" indicating that this method is not defined at all in this base class, this base class cannot be instantiated directly, only subclasses, and it ***must*** be defined in every instantiated subclass. Otherwise it means exactly that: this method is overridable in a subclass that defines this method with the same signature. Otherwise the subclass method does not override it. There's quite a bit more than that, for more information see your C++ book.

Comment: ok, so after getting my knowledge about "virtual" keyword right again I see, that I missunderstood "virtual" as an equivalent to "abstract" in java. But that is, as you said `... =0;` So thank you very much for that! I declared it virtual properly, used override and now it works!

Comment: Ok, now I had a dataleak. Could you explain to me the following behavior:
The class GameObject has a Destructor which calls a virtual function unload().
Map overrides unload() function and has an empty Destructor. Now I expected, since the Base class destructor is called at the end, that it would call the overriden unload() function. Is it because the class Map is destroyed at the time where GameObject's destructor is called?

Comment: Yes, when a base class's destructor gets called, the derived class is already destroyed, and no longer overrides anything.

Comment: ok thanks! Would there be a workaround, so anyone who uses the game engine and creates his own object extending GameObject would not need to call the unload function themselfs? I need the unload function, because when the object is out of scope it shall be empty, but still accessable so it can quickly be loaded again. So it will be filled and emptied often before beeing destroyed.

Comment: Call it in the derived class's destructor. That's what it's there for.

Comment: so no. Well! Then thank you very much! you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that Java methods are virtual by default c++ methods aren't, you need to explicitly mark any methods you want to be virtual with the `virtual` keyword.

```
class GameObject {
    public:
        virtual void loadFromJson(nlohmann::json& json);
        void load();
    // [...] not relevant
}
```

Its a good idea to mark your derived methods with `override` so the compiler raises an error if your method doesn't override a base class method:

```
class Map : public GameObject {
    public:
        void loadFromJson(nlohmann::json& json) override;
        // [...] not relevant
}
```